# Why I cannot say "他坐着在沙发上看报纸“？

Tags: grammar

```
他坐着在沙发上看报纸. He is sitting on the sofa and reading newspaper.
```

A friend tells me it should be

(1) 他坐在沙发上看报纸.

(2) 他坐在沙发上看着报纸.

(3) 他在沙发上坐着看报纸.

Can anyone explain to me **why the original one is wrong?**

Answer (score 2):

着 is a strong termination mark for an adverbial clause.

> 他坐着吃饭 = 他 / 坐着 / 看书
>
> 他笑着回答 = 他 / 笑着 / 回答
>
> 他哭着跑开 = 他 / 哭着 / 跑开

着 here terminate the whole adverbial clauses.

> 你哭着 *you crying* + 你对我说 *you say to me* = 你哭着对我说 *you say to me in tears*

One can easily separate out 哭着 because it's a whole.

---

Back to your original question, 着 has to be at the end of the clause, and hence 在沙发上坐着 (not *坐着在沙发上*). It will be understood as

> 他 / 在沙发上坐着 / 看报纸。

However, the sentence is also grammatically correct if you add a comma after 着. It will sound like there are two predicates rather than one (modified by an adverbial clause).

> 他坐着，在沙发上看报纸。
>
> He is sitting, **and** reading newspapers on the sofa.

In general, anything that belongs to an adverbial clause should go before 着.

---

One exception though is when the verb is transitive.

> 孩子 / 抱着妈妈 / 哭了起来。 *Hugging his mother, the child started to cry.*

In this case, the object can be put after 着.

Answer (score 1):

着= "ing"

他坐着在沙发上看报纸 Have two verb.  S + V(ing)(sitting) + V(ing)(reading) + O(newspaper)+adj( on the sofa )

There is two verb but only one S without conjunction.

You could said: 他在沙发上坐着"且"在看着报纸。

He is sitting on the sofa and reading the newspaper.

S + V + O + conjunction + V2 + O2

(1) 他坐在沙发上看报纸. S + adj(坐在沙發上 sitting on the sofa) + V (reading)+ O (newspaper)

(2) 他坐在沙发上看着报纸. S + adj(坐在沙發上 sitting on the sofa) + V(ing) (reading)+ O (newspaper)

(3) 他在沙发上坐着看报纸. S + adj(在沙發上坐着 sitting on the sofa) + V (reading)+ O (newspaper)

PS:  在沙发上坐着 = 坐在沙发上 = sitting on the sofa

It's hard to explain, hope I express clearly enough.

Comment: Careful - we don't use 著 for 着 outside of Taiwan. 著 usually means 著名.

Comment: I do not clearly understand :(